# How to make a specific function run after every line of code is executed in R?

Tags: r

It is possible to make a function run every time a command *errors* like so

```
options("error" = function() {print("hi")})
```

How can I achieve the same thing, but make the function run *after **every** R command*? (not just the ones that error)

#### Test to see if it worked

Suppose I could set some option `onCodeExecution` like so

```r
options("onCodeExecution" = function() {set.seed(123})
```

Then

```
set.seed(123)
runif(1,0,1);runif(1,0,1)
```

Would return

```r
[1] 0.2875775
[1] 0.2875775
```

rather than

```
[1] 0.2875775
[1] 0.7883051
```

Comment: You could potentially use `source` and `readLines` to increment along a connection to a file.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I understand now, that's a very creative solution. But I think setting some option (if possible) could be much more elegant (and would not involve refactoring any existing code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `addTaskCallback` which is called every time a function is executed.

```
addTaskCallback(function(...) {set.seed(123);TRUE})

runif(1,0,1)
#[1] 0.2875775

runif(1,0,1)
#[1] 0.2875775
```