# How to make a specific function run BEFORE every line of code is executed in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to make a piece of code run before every command?

Just an example of my usecase (not the actual usecase). printing hi before every command

```
> print(2)
> print(1)
```

should give

```
hi
2
hi
1
```

So, there should be a function say `beforeTaskCall(print("hi"))` which will call `print("hi")` before every line.

I found the [addTaskCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988143/how-to-make-a-specific-function-run-after-every-line-of-code-is-executed-in-r) which will make a function run after every command.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/5-ways-to-measure-running-time-of-r-code/

Comment: @flxflks I edited the question to make the language clear. 
 I don't want to calculate the time manually before every command. I just want something that will be executed before my main command.

Comment: See https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/profiling-r-code/

Comment: @G.Grothendieck sorry for the confusion. Your answer fits the usecase I described earlier but that was just an example. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a piece of code before a command you can redefine an unary operator and place this before the command.

```
`~` <- function(x) {print("hi"); eval(substitute(x))}

~print(2)
#[1] "hi"
#[1] 2

~print(1)
#[1] "hi"
#[1] 1
```

Other possible unary operators are `-`, `+`, `?` of `!`.
Or use binary operator, in case it could be placed after the function

```
`?` <- function(x, .) {print("hi"); eval(substitute(x))}

print(2) ?.
#[1] "hi"
#[1] 2
```

---

Another option will be to store the commands as a string and iterate over them.

```
s <- c(r"(print(2)
print(1))")

for(x in strsplit(s, "\n")[[1]]) {
  print("hi")
  eval(parse(text=x))
}
#[1] "hi"
#[1] 2
#[1] "hi"
#[1] 1
```

---

Or make use of `addTaskCallback`, which is calling the function afterwards but maybe it could be used in this setup.

```
invisible(id <- addTaskCallback(function(...) {print("hi"); TRUE}))
#[1] "hi"
print(2)
#[1] 2
#[1] "hi"
invisible(removeTaskCallback(id))
print(1)
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Approach 1: `trace`

Use `trace` to insert arbitrary R expressions (R code) into any places inside a function.

```r
f <- function(x) {
    print(x * 10)
    print(x * 100)
} # Our original function f
m <- expression(print("hello"), print("world")) # An expression m we want to insert into function f
# m <- quote({print("hello"); print("world")}) # Alternative way of defining m
# m <- substitute({print("hello"); print("world")}) # Alternative way of defining m
trace(f, tracer = m, print = FALSE) # Insert expression m at the beginning of function f
f # Check that this function is in trace mode, and read the instruction for seeing tracing code
body(f) # See that our code is inserted correctly
f(3)
[1] "hello"
[1] "world"
[1] 30
[1] 300

untrace(f) # Remove all tracing code
f(3)
[1] 30
[1] 300
```

With this approach you can insert code at any places inside a function utilizing `tracer`, `exit`, `at` argument of `trace`, or even interactively edit the function with `edit = TRUE` argument:
**Beginning**:

```r
trace(f, tracer = m, print = FALSE)
body(f)
{
    .doTrace(expression(print("hello"), print("world")))
    {
        print(x * 10)
        print(x * 100)
    }
}
```

**End**:

```r
trace(f, exit = m, print = FALSE)
body(f)
{
    on.exit(.doTrace(expression(print("hello"), print("world"))))
    {
        print(x * 10)
        print(x * 100)
    }
}
```

**Inside**:

```r
trace(f, m, at = 3, print = FALSE)
body(f)
{
    print(x * 10)
    {
        .doTrace(expression(print("hello"), print("world")))
        print(x * 100)
    }
}
```

**Interactive**:

```r
trace(f, edit = TRUE, print = FALSE)
# supply your custom version of f using an editor
body(f) # for checking
```

## Approach 2: Build a new function based on `body(f)`

```r
f <- function(x) {
    print(x * 10)
    print(x * 100)
} # Our original function f
h_f <- f # copy function f as template
body(h_f) <- substitute({print("hello"); print("world"); m}, list(m = body(f))) # change only body(h_f) to suit our needs
# body(h_f) <- bquote({print("hello"); print("world"); .(body(f))}) # Alternative way of defining body(h_f)
h_f # to check the resulting h_f function
#function (x) 
#{
#    print("hello")
#    print("world")
#    {
#        print(x * 10)
#        print(x * 100)
#    }
#}

h_f(3)
[1] "hello"
[1] "world"
[1] 30
[1] 300
```

Comment: seems a good approach. Is there any way that we can apply trace to all the functions of a file?
Otherwise, effort-wise, it will be the same as defining a new function for every command right?

Comment: I was surprised to learn that even functions are copy-on-write in R.